# python matplotlib , spacing between specific subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So, have created 8 subplots, and i want there to be a spacing between subplot2 and subplot 3,  also between subplot 6 and 7. Something like this:
[image]

These are the plots I get, I am trying to figure out how to achieve this.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Create the main subplot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(20, 18))

 # Subplot 1
ax1 = axs[0, 0]
ax1.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax1.set_title('Subplot 1')
ax1.set_position([0.0, 0.6, 0.125, 0.125])
# Subplot 2
ax2 = axs[0, 1]
ax2.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax2.set_title('Subplot 2')
ax2.set_position([0.25, 0.6, 0.125, 0.125])

# Subplot 3
ax3 = axs[0, 2]
ax3.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax3.set_title('Subplot 3')
ax3.set_position([0.75, 0.6, 0.125, 0.125])
# Subplot 4
ax4 = axs[0, 3]
ax4.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax4.set_title('Subplot 4')
ax4.set_position([1, 0.6, 0.125, 0.125])

# Subplot 5
ax5 = axs[1, 0]
ax5.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax5.set_title('Subplot 5')
ax5.set_position([0, 0.3, 0.125, 0.125])


# Subplot 6
ax6 = axs[1, 1]
ax6.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax6.set_title('Subplot 6')
ax6.set_position([0.25, 0.3, 0.125, 0.125])

# Subplot 7
ax7 = axs[1, 2]
ax7.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax7.set_title('Subplot 7')
ax7.set_position([0.75, 0.3, 0.125, 0.125])

# Subplot 8
ax8 = axs[1, 3]
ax8.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax8.set_title('Subplot 8')
ax8.set_position([1, 0.3, 0.125, 0.125])

# Adjust the spacing between subplots
fig.tight_layout()

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0.4)

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide the code sample that is in charge to plot your charts please

Comment: hi, i have attached a screenshot of the code above.

Comment: Provide it in a code block so i can copy paste it and test it on my own thanks.
Code block  : ```python YOUR CODE ```

Comment: provided in code block now

Comment: A few days ago I posted an answer (I'd say an excellent answer), but I've received zero feedback from you. Do you have solved on your own? do you just don't care anymore? or have you found my solution satisfactory?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can use a new Matplotlib's feature, `subfigures`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('fig title')
sfigs = fig.subfigures(2,2)

for sfig in sfigs.flatten():
    ax0, ax1 = sfig.subplots(1, 2)
    ax0.plot((0,1),(0,1)) ; ax1.plot((0,1),(0,1))
    sfig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
    sfig.suptitle('aaa')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `subplot2grid` is another way to do this:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((11, 9), (0, 0), rowspan=5, colspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((11, 9), (0, 2), rowspan=5, colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((11, 9), (0, 5), rowspan=5, colspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((11, 9), (0, 7), rowspan=5, colspan=2)
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((11, 9), (6, 0), rowspan=5, colspan=2)
ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((11, 9), (6, 2), rowspan=5, colspan=2)
ax7 = plt.subplot2grid((11, 9), (6, 5), rowspan=5, colspan=2)
ax8 = plt.subplot2grid((11, 9), (6, 7), rowspan=5, colspan=2)
```

[image]

For example for `ax1`, with `(11, 9)`, the main plot window is divided to 11 rows and 9 columns. the second tuple, `(0, 0)`, specifies the location of the upper left corner of each box e.g. row 0 & column 0. `rowspan` and `colspan` are the number of rows and columns that each box will be created by.